# Check in compile-time that javascript / typescript objects correspond to C# object

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, compile-time, strong-typing

We are developing a Web API RESTful service in C# and UI in React + Typescript.

After I renamed/add/remove some proeprties in C# REstAPI models the web UI stopped to work, because I forgot to rename it in UI.

Futhermore it is for me almost impossible to find all usage of API calls of such objects.

I would like to configure strongly typed, compiled time checked system that typescript object will be mapped somehow to C# object and compiler will check it.

I can image that I (programmer) would mark javascript/typescript object with some metadata (C# namespace and class name).

How can I do that.

Comment: Have you tried writing your own compiler? :)

Answer (score 1):

The key to resolving this issue is to abstract out a level to a configurable multi-language definition. From that definition you will be able generate both c# and typescript object definitions. The two major type descriptive options are [Protos](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) , and [OpenApi](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/about/) from Google/Microsoft respectively.

This allows your workflow to become:

1. Change the type configuration.
2. Build the type configuration into the C# and Typescript definitions.
3. Build the C# and Typescript libraries.

This ensures the object definitions are always in sync as the C# and Typescript libraries can depend directly on the auto-generated code.